# Open html section according to what's in the hash

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

as the title says, I am trying to open a section that matches the url hash.
My code works, but it's bugged and I don't know what to do anymore.

Here, I have the following navbar:

```
<li class="navigation-li">
   <a href="#" name="about" class="navigation-a section-to" data-page-section="#about">
      <span class="text-line-wrp">
         <span class="text">Sobre Nós</span>
         <span class="line"></span>
      </span>
      <span class="icon iconwrp square-40"><i class="pe-7s-home"></i></span>
   </a>
</li>

<li class="navigation-li">
   <a href="#" name="services" class="navigation-a section-to" data-page-section="#services">
        <span class="text-line-wrp">
           <span class="text">Serviços</span>
           <span class="line"></span>
        </span>
        <span class="icon iconwrp square-40"><i class="pe-7s-config"></i></span>
   </a>
</li>
```

Each 'li' opens a section, and that code is already developed and working, but, I can't open it using the hashes, it works, but it opens the other sections even if I'm calling just one.

Code for opening sections accordingly to hash:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1)

        setTimeout(function() {
            if (hash) {
                e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
                e.initEvent("click", true, true);
                $('a[data-page-section="#' + hash + '"]')[0].dispatchEvent(e) //open section accordingly to shash
            } else {
                console.log("no hash")
            }
        }, 1000);
    });
</script>
```

Also If I'm coming from another page, all sections will open and if I close and reopen, all sections will open and reopen.

I hope you understand this and thank you in advance.

Comment: If location contains the `#` triggered by clicking anchors browser should automatically scroll to it. Is this not happening? Is it set programmatically?

Comment: There are no scroll events on this website, the sections are hidden, they appear from right to left programmatically. They appear but in a strange way.

Comment: I guess you need to share a [mcve] to be able to solve this

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [`Element.scrollIntoView()`](http://Element.scrollIntoView()) instead of trying to simulate click.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    $('a[data-page-section="' + hash + '"]').get(0).scrollIntoView(true)
});
```

Comment: Thx for the answear, I tried that but it didn't work, altough, I think I wasn't clear enough, the navbar opens sections that are hidden so there is no scroll activity on the website. As the section appearing process requires some elements to have its classes changed, I think it's easier to simulate a click on the navbar.

Comment: What about `$('a[data-page-section="' + hash + '"]').trigger('click')`?

Comment: It's the same result.